# Python's closure - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how closure works in Python.

I feel like add1 should work just fine here. I would expect the variable `x` to have been defined when `helper` is called. However, it is giving me a `Local variable referenced before assignment` error.

`add2` is very similar to `add1`. Instead of assigning x with an integer, it assigns it with a dictionary. The behavior of it is also aligned with what I would expect. `x` is defined and reference-able inside `helper`.

```
import random

def add1():
    x = 0
    def helper():
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return helper

def add2():
    x = {}
    def helper():
        x[random.randint(1,1000)] = 3
        return x
    return helper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = add1()
    a2 = add2()

    # print(a1()) #This causes error
    print(a2()) #{650: 3}
    print(a2()) #{650: 3, 333: 3}
```

What's the logic behind this? What am I doing differently other than that the types of `x` are different?

Comment: You're returning function references, by the way - neither `helper` is ever actually called.

Comment: And even changing that, you won't get additional key/value pairs in subsequent calls of `a2()`, because a new dictionary `x` is defined each time.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Can you elaborate more on `neither helper is ever actually called`? If it isn't getting called why does calling `a2` adds new values to the dictionary every time?

Comment: Oh I see, you're saving a reference to `add2()` and then calling it repeatedly; never mind.

Answer (score 44):

You're expecting the compiler to know that the variable has been bound outside the closure. This is not true, and hence you need to use `nonlocal` to indicate this.

```
def add1():
    x = 0
    def helper():
        nonlocal x
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return helper
```

EDIT By denniss:

`nonlocal` is not necessary in `add2` because it's just modifying `x` and not re-binding it (aka not re-assigning it). Whereas in `add1`, `x= x+1` is a `re-assignment`.

Comment: and how come I don't have to do this for `add2` ?

Comment: Because you never rebind `x` in `add2()`, you only mutate it.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!! GOTCHA ... can you please add that last detail to your answer.... I want to make sure other ppl will see it.

Comment: Also note that you wouldn't need `nonlocal` if you had assigned `x + 1` to a new reference, like `y`. The interpreter will then look up `x` in the surrounding scope. It's when you rebind the same reference that it assumes you're talking about a local variable and can't find it in the local scope.